# ListView Not Scrolling Despitie Having Multiple Cells

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm having issues making my `ListView` not scrolling. Is there some XML I am missing?

**VehicleColorFragment**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vehicle_color, container, false);
    final VehicleColorAdapter mForecastAdapter = new VehicleColorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.vehicle_color_cell , R.id.vehicle_color_textview, new ArrayList<VehicleColor>());

    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.color_list);
    listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

    //Todo: Replace with Adams factory
    ArrayList<VehicleColor> arrayOfVehicles = new ArrayList<VehicleColor>();
    VehicleColor newVehicle1 = new VehicleColor("Red", "#F44336");
    VehicleColor newVehicle2 = new VehicleColor("Blue", "#0D47A1");
    VehicleColor newVehicle3 = new VehicleColor("Black", "#000000");
    arrayOfVehicles.add(newVehicle1);
    arrayOfVehicles.add(newVehicle2);
    arrayOfVehicles.add(newVehicle3);

    mForecastAdapter.addAll(arrayOfVehicles);

    return rootView;
}
```

**fragment_vehicle_color.xml (my fragment layout)**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:weightSum="100"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.roadstruck.mobile.fragments.VehicleSelectorFragment"
android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
android:id="@+id/fragment_color_selector"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/choosen_color_cell"
    android:layout_weight="60"
    android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:topRightRadius="30dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/color_list"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**vehicle_color_cell.xml my listview**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:id="@+id/vehicle_color_cell"
>
<TextView
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/vehicle_color_textview"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:minHeight="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In your adapter you're passing `new ArrayList<VehicleColor>()`. I want to know is your listview populated with items that you're setting.

Comment: Clearly you're not showing the full contents for `fragment_vehicle_color.xml` - what else is in there? And how many items do you have in your `ListView`? Content does actually go off-screen?

Comment: Sorry I aded dummy data, I can edit this and add that. I added three cells. Everything shows up except, but the black cell is off the screen and does not scroll

Comment: I am showing full contents of `fragment_vehicle_color.xml.` What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: You can only have a single root element in a layout file (or any XML file, for that matter). `fragment_vehicle_color.xml` has 2 top-level elements. Was your actual intention to put the `TextView` inside the `LinearLayout`?

Comment: I wanted a text view and than a listview below it. Is there another way to make this work ?

Comment: Just realized some code was cut off !

Comment: It actually is scrolling, it just cuts off the last line !